# start a shellscript with cygwin from a batch file that is in a different directory than C:

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file, cmd, cygwin

I am trying to make my life easier and tried working with scripting.

Since the script I wanna use is a shellscript ( I couldn´t make it work in powershell had a problem in reading the xml file; so a colleague had coded a shell script that I am using now) I am trying to use it in a batch(cmd) file.

So here is the idea on how it should work:

we have a .sh script that is removing all the timestamps in the XML files in that directory that this .sh file is in.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `find . -name "*.xml"`
do
  echo $i; sed -i '/UCOMPSTAMP/d' $i
done

for i in `find . -name "*.xml"`
do
  echo $i; sed -i '/DAT name="UTIMESTAMP"/d' $i
done

for i in `find . -name "*.xml"`
do
  echo $i; sed -i '/DAT name="U_INTF"/d' $i
done

for i in `find . -name "*.xml"`
do
  echo $i; sed -i '/DAT name="U_SVCUSE"/d' $i
done

for i in `find . -name "*.xml"`
do
  echo $i; sed -i '/DAT name="U_FSEQ"/d' $i
done
```

This script is working and deletes the timestamps in my xml file in this directory.
I have a directory U:\bla\bla\compare
I also export both xml files that I am going to compare in that directory.
Lets say XML_LIVE.xml and XML_TEST.xml

now I have a batch(called: "execute_sh.cmd") that tries to open the .sh file:

```
@echo off
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash -l /cygdrive/u/bla/compare/01_remove_timestamps.sh
pause
```

right now it doesnt do anything. Also doesn´t say that it can´t find the path. I tried using ./01_remove_timestamps.sh
U:\bla\Compare\01_remove_timestamps.sh
but I get the error that it couldn´t find the file then. If I try to execute the command in cygwin I have to change the directory with

```
cd /cygdrive/u/bla/compare/
```

and then
./remove_timestamps.sh
and this executes the shellscript so why is this not possible with the .cmd?

and my final .cmd (called: execute_all)

```
call %0\..\execute_sh.cmd"
```

has this code in so I just have to start this .cmd and everything is automatic.

This entire thing works if I put all these .cmd and .sh files and the xml files in my home directory in cygwin -> C:\cygwin64\home\myName

The code would be

```
@echo off
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash -l 01_remove_timestamps.sh
pause
```

But I wanna use the D: Drive and a specific directory there. I hope this is clear to understand my problem.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using bash -c 01_remove_timestamps.sh and not bash -l?

Comment: `cd /cygdrive/u/bla/compare/` should probably read `cd /D "U:\bla\compare"`…

Comment: Thanks for the replies but none of ur suggestions has worked for me